# Seleccionar filas de una tabla y eliminar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño sistema de agregar y eliminar filas en una tabla con [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

Tengo un pequeño error y es que puedo seleccionar una fila de una tabla y,  si quiero eliminarla, sale bien; pero si selecciono varias y luego las deselecciono (no sé si asi se escribe xd) y solo quiero eliminar una fila, se borran todas las filas que deseleccioné. Es decir, si selecciono 5 filas y luego deselecciono 4 porque quiero borrar 1, se borran las 5 en vez de 1.  Aquí un ejemplo del código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#bt_add').click(function(){
    agregar();
  });
  $('#bt_del').click(function(){
    eliminar(id_fila_selected);
  });
  $('#bt_delall').click(function(){
    eliminarTodasFilas();
  });


});

var cont=0;
var id_fila_selected=[];
function agregar(){
  cont++;
  var fila='<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td>'+cont+'</td><td>texto x defecto</td><td>0.00</td></tr>';
    $('#tabla').append(fila);
    reordenar();
  }

  function seleccionar(id_fila){
    if($('#'+id_fila).hasClass('seleccionada')){
      $('#'+id_fila).removeClass('seleccionada');
    }
    else{
      $('#'+id_fila).addClass('seleccionada');
    }
    id_fila_selected.push(id_fila);
  }

  function eliminar(id_fila){
    for(var i=0; i<id_fila.length; i++){
      $('#'+id_fila[i]).remove();
    }
    reordenar();
  }

  function reordenar(){
    var num=1;
    $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function(){
      $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(num);
      num++;
    });
  }
  function eliminarTodasFilas(){
    $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });

  }
```

```css
#content{
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
}

.selected{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selected:hover{
  background-color: #0585C0;
  color: white;
}
.seleccionada{
  background-color: #0585C0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <label>Ejemplo</label>
  <a id="bt_add" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Agregar</a>
  <button id="bt_del" class="btn btn-default">Eliminar</button>
  <button id="bt_delall" class="btn btn-default">Eliminar todo</button>
  <table id="tabla" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Nº</td>
        <td>Descripción</td>
        <td>Precio</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Te he limpiado y ordenado un poco el código y el texto de la pregunta. Si no estás de acuerdo puedes deshacer la edición

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en que en la `function seleccionar(id_fila)` estás añadiendo siempre el id de la fila seleccionada al array de filas seleccionadas, independientemente de si realmente se está seleccionado o deseleccionando.

Una opción para solucionar esto sería modificar la función para que haga `push` si se selecciona, o elimine el id de la fila si se deselecciona, el problema con esta solución es que para ello, como no puedes asegurar en qué posición está el id, debes recorrer todo el array y eliminarlo.

Recomiendo la siguiente solución, porque:

1. Se evita el uso de variables globales (mala práctica en JS)
2. Se aprovecha todo el potencial de jQuery y se reducen líneas de código

```
function seleccionar(id_fila){
    $('#'+id_fila).toggleClass('seleccionada');
}

function eliminarSeleccionados(){
    $('.seleccionada').remove();
    reordenar();
}
```

Comment: hola, listo me solucionaste el problema! Es como soy nuevo en esto de jquery no sabia algunos puntos como estos, culpa mia! :D (y)